# what does "up at the front sat" mean? and is "up" as an adverb?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

> They sat in the high seats at the back of the bus, and Poppy sank into her
> book. **Up at the front sat a European woman** in her forties, dressed in a satin
> suit and high-heeled shoes as if for an outing.

Is "up" in the bold part as an adverb? and the sentence in bold mean "a European woman sat in one of the front seat that was very near to front of the bus"?

when we say "under the tree is a dog" we obviously are saying: there is a dog under the tree.
but in the sentence "up at the front sat a woman" can we write it as

1. there was a woman sitting up at one of the front seats?
2. at the front sat up a woman?

Comment: Please consult the question @EdwinAshworth has linked, as it pertains to the idea of "locative inversion". Your bolded phrase could be rewritten: "A European woman sat [up] at the front of the bus," where the optional "up" could be taken to mean "closer to [somewhere] in relation to my position". Note that if the word "up" is omitted, the phrase becomes a simple statement of the woman's position without any comparative positional reference to the narrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there no subject in a sentence like "Under the tree is a dog"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178705/is-there-no-subject-in-a-sentence-like-under-the-tree-is-a-dog) 'Up' has arguably been called a prepositional-phrase-modifier, but I'd say it has a spatial sense here, and we have essentially a twinned but reduced prepositional locative.

Comment: I edited my question, So, can we say "a woman was sitting up at one of the front seat that was closer to the front of the bus? or can we simply say "a woman was sitting up at one of the front seats"?

Comment: "A woman was sitting **in** one of the front seats." _At_ goes with _front_, and you don't need to explain that the front seats were at the front of the bus!